# When I change the :id param in the url of my vue application, why doesn't the page reload when I press enter?

Tags: vue.js, vue-component, vue-router

I have a vue js application that is using the vue router. I have the following route:

http://server/stores/index.html#/ViewStore/:StoreId

If I change :StoreId in the url and press enter, nothing happens. I have to hit F5 to reload the page and have it process the new :StoreId.

I am using:

```
<router-view :key="$route.fullPath"></router-view>
```

In my App.vue component.

My routes are defined in routes.js as follows:

```
import Home from '@/components/Home';
import EditStore from "@/components/EditStore";
import ViewStore from "@/components/ViewStore";

export const routes = [
    { path: '/', redirect: '/ViewStore/NotFound'  },
    { path: '/StoreListing/:DisplayTarget', component: Home,  },
    { name: 'ViewStore', path: '/ViewStore/:StoreId', component: ViewStore,  },
    { name: 'EditStore', path: '/EditStore/:StoreId/tab/:tab', component: EditStore }
];
```

I am also using:

```
    watch: {
        // call again the method if the route changes
        '$route': 'LoadStore'
    },
```

to reload my component data when the url changes, but still nothing. I'm not sure what I'm doing wrong. I'm getting the same results in IE 11 and Chrome.

Comment: First of all your URL look kinda wired to me, at least it could have been something like: `http://server/stores/#/ViewStore/:StoreId`. Anyhow, can you push programatically and see if you are getting expected result? `this.$router.push({ name: 'ViewStore', params: { StoreId: '1' } })`

Comment: Could you put some logging at the top of the `LoadStore` method to check whether it is being called? There are two possibilities here, either it isn't being called when the route changes or it is being called and it just isn't doing what you want. The current description, *'nothing happens'*, doesn't really clarify which of these two scenarios we're in.

Comment: That does change the URL as expected. But for this, I need to be able to change the :StoreId value in the URL of the address bar and press enter to have the page reload. It doesn't seem like the page loads at all. I don't see any of my log statements in the console.

Comment: @Syed if you'll post your comment as an answer, I'll mark it as the accepted answer. The issue is was having the index.html page in the url.

Comment: @jason I don't think the `index.html` is the root problem. It sounds like you just have a caching problem and the incorrect code is cached under the URL `index.html`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all your URL look kinda weird to me bcoz it has `index.html`, at least it could have been something like:

```
http://server/stores/#/ViewStore/:StoreId
```

Anyhow, can you push programatically and see if you are getting expected result?

```
this.$router.push({ name: 'ViewStore', params: { StoreId: '1' } })
```